# How to assign a value from locals() to a local variable with the same name?

Tags: python, local-variables

This works:

```
def foo():
    locals().update({'bar': 12})
    print(locals()['bar'])  # 12
```

This fails:

```
def foo():
    locals().update({'bar': 12})
    bar = locals()['bar']  # KeyError: 'bar'
    print(bar)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you do such a thing ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This question is mainly of educational nature, although there is an actual use case behind it. I know there are other ways of getting the job done though.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, would you mind telling more about the actual use case ?

Comment: Why not just `bar=12` ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @NitheeshMN this is mentionned as a comment in the code snippet : "KeyError: 'bar'"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sure, I'm using `locals()` to define dictionaries used as configuration objects for machine learning experiments. Here is an example to illustrate: https://gist.github.com/danijar/aa2f414418bce5dabb5fcb84bed54b0c

Comment: @khelwood Because I'm actually updating the locals with a larger dictionary that's defined somewhere else. I'm trying to achieve 'inheritance' between locals :D

Comment: @danijar for your concrete use case, you'd be better using plain dicts instead, really. Abusing `locals()` that way is brittle at best (been here, done that), doesn't help wrt/ readability / testability / maintainability, and - as you may have noticed by now - doesn't work as expected for quite a few cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: This is more of an *abuse* case than a use case, really. (Yes, I just wanted to make that lame joke. Sue me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

> **Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

**Edit:** But as mentioned above, `bar = 12` of course works:

```
>>> def foo():
...     bar = 12
...     bar_ = locals()["bar"]
...     print(bar_)
...     
... 
>>> foo()
12
```

Answer (score 0):

change the name of variable. i mean:

```
bar = locals()['bar']  # KeyError: 'bar'
```

on

```
tmp = locals()['bar'] # 12
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run this code:

```
def foo():
    locals().update({'bar': 12})
    print locals()
    bar = locals()['bar']
```

The output is:
First `{}` gets printed
And then we get a `KeyError`

So, I'm guessing that your `locals` is not getting updated when you try to assign value to a variable (`bar = locals()['bar']`). But it works fine in your first case because you don't do any assignment.

**Edit 1**:
I went through your github link, and I would suggest you to use a `dict` instead of `locals`. For example,

```
def base_config():
    return dict(num_epochs=50, bath_size=200, gradient_clipping=100.0)
```

Comment: I think the problem is when assigning to the name `bar`, Python treats `bar` as a not-yet-defined variable. I'm assuming it's related to performance optimizations of `locals()` sometimes being a dict and sometimes an array.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The problem is that the dict doesn't let me compute some of the values based on the previous values. I would do `config = dict(); config['first_param'] = 12; config['second_param'] = 0.5 * config['first_param']` but I was hoping for a better syntax.